# Acess the dictionary being created inside dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary of numbers to lists of numbers like:

> a = { 1: [2,3,4] , 2: [1,4] }

i want to create a new dictionary with comprehension based on it where each element from each list would be linked to the key to that list.

That would be something like:

> b = { element : [key] for key in a.keys() for element in a[key]}

that gives me of course:

> b = {1: [2], 2: [1], 3: [1], 4: [2]}

instead of

> b = {1: [2], 2: [1], 3: [1], 4: [1,2]}

because the index gets overwritten. so I need to do something like:

```
b = { element : [key] + self[element] for key in a.keys() for element in a[key]}
```

or

```
b = { element +: key for key in a.keys() for element in a[key]}
```

but in a working fashion.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im assuming this is for some form of mapping:

```
from itertools import chain
def makeMap(d):
    nodes = set([x for x in chain.from_iterable(d.values())])
    return dict([[x, [y for y in d.keys() if x in d[y]]] for x in nodes ])
```

this code will do that for you :)

---

EDIT:

and heres the (massive) one liner, I wouldn't recommend putting this in code though, since it's unreadable.

```
def makeMap(d):
    return dict([[x, [y for y in d.keys() if x in d[y]]]
                 for x in set([x for x in chain.from_iterable(d.values())])
                 ])
```

steps:
1. make a set of all the possible node values
2. find all the node values in the dictionary values, if there then put the key it was found in into the mapped to list.

Comment: i wanted to know if its is possible with one line only but your thing is in the spirit of the stuff so its nice but is not doing it right: {1: [2, 3], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2], 4: [1]}

Comment: @user, did you type it in right? This code is working fine on my end, also, i'll change it to a 1 liner for you.

Comment: its ok, it must have been my bad. many thanks for making it one line

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to build your dictionary using `defaultdict` and two loops.

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = { 1: [2,3,4] , 2: [1,4] }
b = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in a.iteritems():
    for elem in value:
        b[elem].append(key)
```

Comment: thanks for your time, didnt know of defaultdict but the real purpose of this was to see if I could make it with list comprehension

Comment: I understand. The oneliner's are very clever, but in production I prefer code that doesn't take 5 minutes to decipher!

Comment: yes sure but im learning the language and that is something that makes me get into its spirit faster

Answer (score 2):

Everything is possible:

```
>>> a = { 1: [2,3,4] , 2: [1,4] }
>>> d={}
>>> for k, v in sum(map(lambda x: zip(x[1], [x[0]]*len(x[1])), a.items()), []):
...   d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
...
>>> d
{1: [2], 2: [1], 3: [1], 4: [1, 2]}
>>>
```

Comment: im new to python so i can't even read that by now but many thanks for it gonna make me learn a lot